# Using Java (Minecraft), how do I calculate and use a quaternion to rotate one unit vector to match another?

Tags: java, vector, graphics, minecraft, quaternions

I am creating a custom sky renderer for Minecraft that tracks objects in a simplified star system and renders them with more realistic movement than vanilla Minecraft. To accomplish this, my plan has been to use vectors to track the current position of the observer's planet, the current rotation of the observer's planet, and the current location of body that should be rendered.

I have gone a few weeks studying vectors and quaternions, finding many answers here on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately I still cannot get this vector/quaternion system to work correctly. One frustrating thing is that because I am working within a larger system, it's hard to tell if my problem has more to do with my math or more to do with the rendering code. I strongly believe it is the math, though, because I can do some basic rotations and confirm the rendering works correctly. It's only when I attempt to use my vector/quaternion system that things go haywire.

Here is an animation made with Mathematica that shows the math I am doing. The black vector is the current rotation of the observer, red is the position of the observer, green is the position of another orbiting planet, and blue is the vector generated when I transform the black rotation vector with the quaternion I generate. This view is from overhear, but the orbital inclinations of each planet is 7 degrees, and the observer's planet is tilted 23 degrees. As you can see, no matter where the black observer rotation and green other planet vectors are pointed, the blue vector always points from the observer's planet to the other planet. (In my simplified example code, the blue vector would follow the red vector exactly, except it would face the opposite way.)

[image: Animated vectors showing the position and rotation of two planets in a star system as well as a vector always pointing from one planet to another.]

The code examples I share below are just for tracking a central sun, not even a planet orbiting the sun. There are simpler and more efficient ways to render a stationary sun, but I figure if my system works correctly in such a scenario, it should work fine elsewhere.

Here is the code I use to track the vectors and calculate a quaternion to rotate the observer's rotation vector (which would be pointing straight up from the ground in Minecraft):

```
public class SkyHelper {

    /**
     * @param time        The number of ticks since the dimension was created.
     * @param siderealDay How many ticks it takes the observer's planet to rotate
     *                    once.
     * @param year        How many ticks it takes for the observer's planet to
     *                    complete an orbit.
     * @param orbitalTilt How many degrees the orbit of the observer's planet is
     *                    tilted from the horizontal.
     * @param axialTilt   How many degrees the axis of the obsever's planet is
     *                    tilted from the vertical.
     * @return A quaternion describing how to rotate the MatrixStack to render the
     *         center in the right place.
     */
    public static Quaternion centralSunQuaternion(long time, float siderealDay, float year, float orbitalTilt,
            float axialTilt, boolean useDegrees) {

        // Determine position in tilted circular orbit.
        float dimensionPositionAngle = (float) time / year % 1.0F * (useDegrees ? 360.0F : 2.0F * (float) Math.PI);
        Vector3f posVec = copyVector(Vector3f.YN);
        Vector3f orbitalTiltAxis = copyVector(Vector3f.ZP);
        Quaternion orbitalTiltQuaternion = rotation(Vector3f.XP, orbitalTilt, useDegrees);
        orbitalTiltAxis.transform(orbitalTiltQuaternion);
        Quaternion dimensionPositionQuaternion = rotation(orbitalTiltAxis, dimensionPositionAngle, useDegrees);
        posVec.transform(orbitalTiltQuaternion);
        posVec.transform(dimensionPositionQuaternion);
        posVec = normalizeVector(posVec);

        // Determine current rotation of planet around tilted axis.
        float dimensionRotationAngle = (((float) time / siderealDay) % 1.0F
                * (radians ? 360.0F : 2.0F * (float) Math.PI));
        Vector3f rotVec = copyVector(Vector3f.YN);
        Vector3f axialTiltAxis = copyVector(Vector3f.ZP);
        Quaternion axialTiltQuaternion = rotation(Vector3f.XP, axialTilt, useDegrees);
        axialTiltAxis.transform(axialTiltQuaternion);
        Quaternion dimensionRotationQuaternion = rotation(axialTiltAxis, dimensionRotationAngle, useDegrees);
        rotVec.transform(axialTiltQuaternion);
        rotVec.transform(dimensionRotationQuaternion);
        rotVec = normalizeVector(rotVec);

        // Quaternion from rotation vector to position vector.
        Vector3f cross = crossVectors(rotVec, posVec);
        float dot = dotVectors(rotVec, posVec);
        float r = dot + 1.0F;
        Quaternion quat = Quaternion.ONE;
        if (dot < -0.999999F) {
            quat = rotation(Vector3f.XP, 180.0F, false);
        } else if (dot < 0.999999F) {
            quat = new Quaternion(cross.x(), cross.y(), cross.z(), r);
        }
        quat = normalizeQuaternion(quat);

        return quat;

    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static Quaternion rotation(Vector3f vector, float angle, boolean useDegrees) {
        return new Quaternion(vector, angle, useDegrees);
    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static Vector3f copyVector(Vector3f vector) {
        return new Vector3f(vector.x(), vector.y(), vector.z());
    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static Vector3f normalizeVector(Vector3f vec) {
        float squareSum = vec.x() * vec.x() + vec.y() * vec.y() + vec.z() * vec.z();
        if ((double) squareSum < 1.0E-5D) {
            return vec;
        } else {
            float inverseRoot = 1.0F / (float) Math.sqrt(squareSum);
            vec.set(vec.x() * inverseRoot, vec.y() * inverseRoot, vec.z() * inverseRoot);
            return vec;
        }
    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static Quaternion normalizeQuaternion(Quaternion quat) {
        float squareSum = quat.i() * quat.i() + quat.j() * quat.j() + quat.k() * quat.k() + quat.r() * quat.r();
        if (squareSum > 1.0E-6F) {
            float inverseRoot = 1.0F / (float) Math.sqrt(squareSum);
            quat.set(quat.i() * inverseRoot, quat.j() * inverseRoot, quat.k() * inverseRoot, quat.r() * inverseRoot);
        } else {
            quat.set(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
        }
        return quat;
    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static Vector3f crossVectors(Vector3f vec0, Vector3f vec1) {
        return new Vector3f(vec0.y() * vec1.z() - vec0.z() * vec1.y(), vec0.z() * vec1.x() - vec0.x() * vec1.z(),
                vec0.x() * vec1.y() - vec0.y() * vec1.x());
    }

    /** The vanilla version of this method only exists on the client. */
    public static float dotVectors(Vector3f vec0, Vector3f vec1) {
        return vec0.x() * vec1.x() + vec0.y() * vec1.y() + vec0.z() * vec1.z();
    }

}
```

The `transform` method is of the form `qvq*`, which rotates the given vector using the given quaternion.

Here is the code I use to render the sun given the quaternion from SkyHelper:

```
public class MystcraftSkyRenderer {

    private static final ResourceLocation SUN_LOCATION = new ResourceLocation("textures/environment/sun.png");

    public static void render(int ticks, float partialTicks, MatrixStack matrixStack, ClientWorld world,
            Minecraft minecraftInstance) {

        TextureManager textureManager = minecraftInstance.getTextureManager();
        BufferBuilder bufferbuilder = Tessellator.getInstance().getBuilder();

        // A solar Minecraft day is 24000 ticks or 20 real minutes (20 ticks/sec * 60
        // sec/min * 20 min).
        float overworldSolarDay = 20.0F * 60.0F * 20.0F;
        overworldSolarDay = 300.0F; // 30 seconds for testing.
        // For our purposes, we define a Minecraft year as 5 real days.
        float overworldYear = overworldSolarDay * 3.0F * 24.0F * 5.0F;
        overworldYear = overworldSolarDay * 1000.0F; // 5 minutes for testing.
        // Sidereal day is slightly shorter than solar day.
        float overworldSiderealDay = overworldSolarDay - (overworldSolarDay / overworldYear);

        float axialTilt = 90.0F;
        float orbitalTilt = 0.0F;

        renderSingleSun(matrixStack, bufferbuilder, textureManager, world, world.getDayTime(), overworldSiderealDay,
                overworldYear, orbitalTilt, axialTilt, true);

        RenderSystem.depthMask(true);
        RenderSystem.disableFog();

    }

    public static void renderSingleSun(MatrixStack matrixStack, BufferBuilder bufferbuilder,
            TextureManager textureManager, ClientWorld world, long ticks, float siderealDay, float year,
            float orbitalTilt, float axialTilt, boolean useDegrees) {

        Quaternion quaternion = SkyHelper.centralSunQuaternion(ticks, siderealDay, year, orbitalTilt, axialTilt,
                useDegrees);

        // Render.
        matrixStack.pushPose();
        matrixStack.mulPose(quaternion);
        Matrix4f matrix4f = matrixStack.last().pose();
        float radius = 30.0F;
        textureManager.bind(SUN_LOCATION);
        bufferbuilder.begin(7, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX);
        bufferbuilder.vertex(matrix4f, -radius, 100.0F, -radius).uv(0.0F, 0.0F).endVertex();
        bufferbuilder.vertex(matrix4f, radius, 100.0F, -radius).uv(1.0F, 0.0F).endVertex();
        bufferbuilder.vertex(matrix4f, radius, 100.0F, radius).uv(1.0F, 1.0F).endVertex();
        bufferbuilder.vertex(matrix4f, -radius, 100.0F, radius).uv(0.0F, 1.0F).endVertex();
        bufferbuilder.end();
        WorldVertexBufferUploader.end(bufferbuilder);
        matrixStack.popPose();

    }

}
```

The most frustrating part of all this is that when I transform the observer's rotation vector using the quaternion, it definitely turns into the position vector (which is pointing right at the sun). But when it comes time to render, it does not appear in the right place.

If it helps understand my code better, if no rotation were applied, the sun would appear unmoving directly above the planet (noon position). So moving along observer's local y-axis would be "up" and "down" in the game.

I'm happy to provide more examples and/or information as requested.

Comment: The whole point of SO is to be a resource for _future_ readers.  Links go 404.  If the question doesn't stand on its own, without needing external links, it will eventually die.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've read it but missed that part. Adding code directly now.